# Google Search Engine Effect and auto complete

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete, search-engine

I am working in my company website which it has a front o index page like Google with a search form. I would like to create the same effect as Google, once someone start looking for any product, it will switch from having a search form in the center of page to having it in the top of page, plus having the auto complete search field.

I am using the PHP and MySQL for my website.

I would appreciate any feedback since I got a deadline set by my boss.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Cheers.

Comment: you can do it with jquery and ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way of changing the page is using jQuery's .change() function for it: 
http://api.jquery.com/change/

But it will be some work to acquire that effect.

For auto completion you can use jQueryUI's Autocomplete:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete

Hope it helps and good luck with your deadline ;)